# VS2019 No intellisense in Razor pages due RemoteInvocationException

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Every time I enter in a razor Page (aspnet core 5 or prior) VS2019 raises this exception.

I don't know if this is the cause, but I don't have Intellisense in any part of a razor pages (eg. Model., @Html.   or object.)

[image]

ALL THE EXTENSION ARE DISABLED, so not their fault....

Activity.xml Log has this error

Any Help ?

StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException: No method by the name 'textDocument/documentHighlight' is found.at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.d__133`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServer.Client.JsonRpcExtensionMethods.<SendMethodRequestAsync>d__1`2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServer.Client.RemoteDocumentHighlightBroker.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<g__DocumentHighlighRequest|0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServer.Client.StreamingRequestBroker`3.<DoStreamingRequestAsync>d__5.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.ThreadingTools.<WithCancellationSlow>d__8`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServer.Client.SynchronizationManager.d__5`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServer.Client.DocumentHighlightTagger.<UpdateDocumentHighlightsAsync>d__25.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsTaskLibraryHelper.<>c__DisplayClass35_0.<<FileAndForget>b__0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject) RPC server exception: StreamJsonRpc.RemoteMethodNotFoundException: No method by the name 'textDocument/documentHighlight' is found.at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<InvokeCoreAsync>d__133`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServer.Client.JsonRpcExtensionMethods.d__0`2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServer.Client.RemoteLanguageServiceBroker.<RequestAsync>d__304.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.ThreadingTools.<WithCancellationSlow>d__8`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServer.Client.SynchronizationManager.d__5`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServer.Client.RemoteLanguageServiceBroker.<RequestAsync>d__248.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServer.ContainedLanguage.DefaultLSPRequestInvoker.<RequestServerCoreAsync>d__7`2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServerClient.Razor.HtmlCSharp.DocumentHighlightHandler.d__5.MoveNext()

Comment: Are you running the most recent (all updates) version of VS 2019?

Comment: yes I do (16.8.6); after further investigation I found that it happens only when the solution has 2 (or more) projects